# Trying to reassign and output new set values in Java

Tags: java

I am trying to create a fun Java "Gibberish Translator" for my little brother. He is mentally disabled and I believe he will get a kick out of this. :) I know how to accept input and how to display output. What I am wanting to do, however, is far above my Java knowledge. (If it is even at all possible.) I am hoping that when my brother types something in a text field and then presses a button, a totally different text will display in a text area. I am hoping to be able to assign **different** letters or letter combinations to each letter. This way, every time he uses the letter "i", for example, it will always display "ti" instead. I am wanting the output to be totally gibberish and funny to read. If this is possible to do, please help me with assigning, and outputting different set values to each letter. I am fairly new to coding, so please include examples.

Thanks in advance.

(I have not inserted code as of yet because I have not started coding on the computer yet. I want to make sure it can be done before I begin the hard work. :))

Comment: Go ahead, Bro. Everything is possible.

Comment: Do you always want "ti" to be displayed when "i" is hit? Or when "i" is hit can it be a random output?

Comment: i want it to always be the same. That way, the word "the" will always be the same gibberish text.

Comment: I just want to say how awesome it is that you are taking on this project for your brother.  Best of luck to you.  Both of the answers so far will help you get started.

Answer (score 3):

Totally gibberish is harder to define than it is to describe.  In other words, after you implement a translation pattern, it won't look like "total gibberish" to you.  To paraphrase with your example, it will look like all "i"s were translated to "ti"s.

That said, you can easily do something that involves having a "input" set of data that "maps" to an "output" set of characters.  Something like

```
i -> ti
j -> kj
l -> vn
```

and so on.  Then you "substitute" the output for the input one character at a time.  If you pick the "right side" of the "map" of input to output carefully, you can even "reverse" the map, or make a backwards translator.  Not every map can be reversed, but this exercise will give you a good understanding of key mathematical (not in the number sense of the word) concepts.

Do translations manually at least five (or more times).  Concentrate on the steps you follow to do this manually, because they will become the steps you need to "code" into your program.  Odds are they will look something like this (but don't take my word for it, discover it for yourself)

1. Look at the "next" character
2. Find it in the "input" side of the translation "map"
3. Read the "output" side of the "map entry" you just accessed
4. Write the current "output" translation down on the paper
5. Repeat at step #1 until "out of characters"

As you get stuck, feel free to post more questions.  Try to keep the question specific and provide a code example.  To get the most out of a question, follow the advice of ["How to ask good questions"](http://www.gerv.net/hacking/how-to-ask-good-questions/).  Doing so will get you the most help.

Answer (score 1):

Create a `Map<Character, String>`, containing the replacement text for each character. Iterate through all the chars of the input string, and append the replacement found in the map to a `StringBuilder`.

Here's some code. You just have to add additional replacements to the map:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Gibberish {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(gibberish("Hi, I'm Jim"));
    }

    public static String gibberish(String input) {
        Map<Character, String> replacements = new HashMap<Character, String>();
        replacements.put('i', "ti");
        // ...

        StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
        for (char c : input.toCharArray()) {
            String replacement = replacements.get(c);
            // if no replacement, we keep the character
            if (replacement == null) {
                output.append(c);
            }
            else {
                output.append(replacement);
            }
        }
        return output.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not homework at all. It is for my "special" brother. He has created a pretend language that our cat speaks. I wanted to create something that he could play around with to gather pretend phrases in this "language". I need help writing the code because I am a noob at java and coding. All help is appreciated.